# PHP SOAPClient WCF Error sending parameters

Tags: php, wcf, web-services, soap, soap-client

I'm working on a Webservice using PHP SoapClient.

The webservice url is: http://web.abaseguros.com/AutoConnect/ACCatalogos.svc?wsdl

And here is my code:

```
<?php

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$pin = new SoapClient("http://web.abaseguros.com/AutoConnect/ACCatalogos.svc?wsdl");

class Token {
    var $usuario;
    var $password;
    function Token($user,$pass) {
        $this->usuario = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;
    }
}

//User and Password for the token object
$Token = new Token('usuarioWCF','Pa$$w0rd');    

//XML 'Entrada' String
$Entrada = "<CAT><NEG>5786</NEG></CAT>"; 

$result = $pin->ObtenerMarcas($Token,$Entrada);
```

But PHP prints out the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed] when i execute the script.

The company gave me a sample code written on C#

```
private void Obtener_Catalogo_ABASeguros()
{
string strEntrada, strSalida;

strEntrada = “<CAT><NEG>5786</NEG></CAT>“; +

ACCatalogosClient proxy = new ACCatalogosClient();


Token token = new Token();
token.usuario = "usuarioWCF";
token.password = "Pa$$w0rd";

try
{
    strSalida = proxy.ObtenerMarcas(token, strEntrada);
}
catch (FaultException<Error> ex)
    {
    txtCotSalida.Text = string.Format("Ocurrio un error en el WCF:\n " +
       "Origen: {0}\n "+
       "Mensaje: {1}\n "+
       "Stack: {2}", ex.Detail.Origen,        ex.Detail.Mensaje, ex.Detail.StackTrace);
}
```

But I'm still unabled to understand how parameters are sent on both languages.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Your Soap client does not know how to deserialize the object Token. You need to convert that token object into a associate array and use that array as parameter to the operation instead.

```
$pin->ObtenerMarcas(get_object_vars($Token),$Entrada);
```

I am afraid even you get this error cleared, you will not be successful in working with the service yet. It looks like the a token is required in the soap header instead. the C code you put does not show you everything, it has the implementation encapsulated inside the Proxy class. You need to have a read the documentation is there's any, otherwise you will have to read the imported wsdl files embedded in your provided global wsdl link.

Comment: It didnt work,

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed] The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ObtenerMarcas'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''.

Comment: Yes i was tinking on sending sap headers with the token object but there is no documentation about it.

Comment: worth having a look at the implementation inside the c proxy class. Sorry, can't help much without documentation